# Why I can't copy/save images from source folder to destination folder?

Tags: android, image

Now i am developing a Whatsapp Statues downloader Application. I done to show the images from Whatsapp folder to my application Recyclerview. Now i stuck at saving the image files, source folder to destination folder.

On click method at my RecyclerView:

```
                        holder.mImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                     @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                      //mDataset is contain the Image files

                        try {

                         file_operation.save(mDataset.get(ourPosition));

                            Toast.makeText(mContext, "saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            Toast.makeText(mContext, "saving failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
```

My saveImage class:

```
    package com.example.storage;

    import android.os.Environment;

    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import java.io.FileOutputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;

    public class file_operation {


   public static void save(File sourcefile) throws IOException {
    File f3 = sourcefile;
    String filename = f3.getName();
    File desti_file = new File(Environment.getDataDirectory().toString() + FilesData.getSavedFilesLocation(), filename);

     if (!desti_file.exists()) {
        desti_file.mkdir();
         }
     if (!desti_file.getParentFile().exists()) {
        desti_file.mkdirs();
         }
     if (!desti_file.exists()) {
        desti_file.createNewFile();
         }

     FileChannel source = null;
     FileChannel destination = null;

    try {
        source = new FileInputStream(f3).getChannel();
        destination = new FileOutputStream(desti_file).getChannel();

        // inChannel.transferTo(0, inChannel.size(), outChannel);
        source.transferTo(0, source.size(), destination);
        // destination.transferFrom(source, 0, source.size());
    } finally {
        if (source != null) {
            source.close();
        }
        if (destination != null) {
            destination.close();
        }
    }
    FilesData.scrapSavedFiles();

}
```

}

When i Run the application i always get "Saving Failed" Toast message. I tried many ways but i can't save the image.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see from your "Saving Failed" Toast Message It is going in catch with an exception. Can you paste your stack trace or error log here.

Comment: **06-27 14:16:06.337 15120-15120/com.example.storage I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
06-27 14:16:06.562 15120-15120/com.example.storage E/MultiWindowProxy: getServiceInstance failed!
    
    --------- beginning of system
06-27 14:16:06.945 15120-15120/com.example.storage E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
06-27 14:16:23.323 15120-15159/com.example.storage E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xa01a45e0**